# Как правильно осуществлять привязку булевского свойства с помощью .bind() в JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

Имеется диалоговое окно с полями ввода имени и фамилии. Допустим, обязательным полем ввода является только соответствующее фамилии. Нужно добиться того, чтобы пока введённая фамилия не будет валидной, кнопка "Сохранить" (`acceptEditingButton`) была неактивной.

```java
public class PersonEditDialogController {

  @FXML private TextField familyName_InputField;
  private String inputtedValidFamilyName;
  private boolean inputtedFamilyNameIsValid;

  private BooleanProperty requiredInputFieldValuesAreValid;


  @FXML private TextField familyNameSpell_InputField;
  @FXML private TextField givenName_InputField;

  @FXML private Button acceptEditingButton;


  @FXML
  private void initialize() {

    familyName_InputField.focusedProperty().addListener(
        (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> { if (!newValue) { onFamilyNameInputFiledLostFocus(); } }
    );

    requiredInputFieldValuesAreValid = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
    acceptEditingButton.disableProperty().bind(requiredInputFieldValuesAreValid);
  }


  @FXML
  private void onFamilyNameInputFiledLostFocus() {

    String inputtedFamilyName = familyName_InputField.getText();

    if (Person.isFamilyNameValid(inputtedFamilyName)) {
      this.inputtedValidFamilyName = inputtedFamilyName;
      this.inputtedFamilyNameIsValid = true;
      // Допустим, что обязательным полем ввода является только фамилия
      this.requiredInputFieldValuesAreValid.setValue(true);
    } else {
      this.inputtedFamilyNameIsValid = false;
      requiredInputFieldValuesAreValid.setValue(false);
    }
  }
}
```

Приведённый выше код отрабатывает без ошибок, тем не менее, тем не менее, привязка `requiredInputFieldValuesAreValid` осуществлена некорректно: несмотря на то, что в методе `initialize()` я инициализирую `requiredInputFieldValuesAreValid = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);`, кнопка не то что активна, на ней ещё и фокус есть (для дефолтного стиля Windows это эффект свечения синим).

Comment: я не пойму зачем нужен `requiredInputFieldValuesAreValid` если и так есть флаг `inputtedFamilyNameIsValid` и судя по коду семантика у них одна и та же. Что мешает сделать `acceptEditingButton.setDisabled(true)` или `false`?

Comment: @Tsyklop, для мастабируемости приложения. Сейчас у меня обязательное поле только одно, но потом, возможно, я захочу добавить другие обязательные поля. Таким образом, сколько бы у нас обязательных полей не было - одно или несколько - `requiredInputFieldValuesAreValid` бессменно остаётся шлагбаумом, который не пропустит данные к сохранению, покуда они не будут валидными.

Comment: С тем же успехом можно сделать простое `boolean` поле и не привязывать его куда либо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас логика перепутана, должно быть disabe = true, если valid = false

```
acceptEditingButton.disableProperty().bind(requiredInputFieldValuesAreValid.not());
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! И правда, я немного запутался.